# Setting scale_x_discrete limits removes both geom_point and geom_line from my ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am plotting 4 lines using ggplot2, showing numeric values on the y-axis and months in a calendar year on the x-axis. I am using a data frame like this:

| month | mean_ride_type | mean_ride_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| September | weekend_mem | 10218.25 |
| September | weekday_mem | 40209.84 |
| September | weekend_cas | 10399.10 |
| September | weekday_cas | 24094.11 |

The month and mean_ride_type columns are character type; the mean_ride_count column is numeric type. The data repeats in the same way -- 4 mean_ride_type values per month -- for every month in a calendar year.

I can plot these lines using the following `ggplot` code:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = mean_ride_count, group = mean_ride_type))
plot <- plot + geom_line(aes(color = mean_ride_type), size = 1) + geom_point()
plot
```

And the plot looks fine.

The months are sorted alphabetically, but for my plot I want them to be sorted chronologically, beginning in May. So in my ggplot code I employ the `scale_x_discrete()` function.

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = mean_ride_count, group = mean_ride_type)) + scale_x_discrete(limits = month_order)
plot <- plot + geom_line(aes(color = mean_ride_type), size = 1) + geom_point()
plot
```

..where `month_order` is a vector with values of strings of months, beginning in May, like I want.

But when I run the above code, the plot only shows 4 points, when it should show 48. There are no lines, when before there were 4 lines. All the points are in the month of September, and I can't understand why. The months are in the order I want on the x-axis, which is cool. Also there are a couple of alerts:

```
 - geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

 - Removed 44 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).

 - Removed 44 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

I am at a loss. Especially since I used the `scale_x_discrete()` function, with the same vector used for limits, on another plot with no problems whatsoever.

I couldn't find a similar problem on the web. And I've moved the `scale_x_discrete()` function around within the code, but the result is the same.

Here are my data:

```
structure(list(month = c("September", "September", "September", 
"September", "May      ", "May      ", "May      ", "May      ", 
"June     ", "June     ", "June     ", "June     ", "April    ", 
"April    ", "April    ", "April    ", "December ", "December ", 
"December ", "December ", "July     ", "July     ", "July     ", 
"July     ", "March    ", "March    ", "March    ", "March    ", 
"January  ", "January  ", "January  ", "January  ", "August   ", 
"August   ", "August   ", "August   ", "February ", "February ", 
"February ", "February ", "October  ", "October  ", "October  ", 
"October  ", "November ", "November ", "November ", "November "
), mean_ride_type = c("average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekend_member_ride_count", "average_weekend_casual_ride_count", 
"average_weekday_member_ride_count", "average_weekday_casual_ride_count"
), mean_ride_count = c(10218.25, 10566.5, 9980.38888888889, 5771.88888888889, 
4022.86666666667, 3572.4, 3313.875, 2082.6875, 7184.83333333333, 
7078.5, 6379.3125, 4361, 6739.15384615385, 5834.84615384615, 
6648.23529411765, 3573.41176470588, 2974.41666666667, 1095.66666666667, 
3463.15789473684, 891.157894736842, 9259.76923076923, 11316.7692307692, 
8989.27777777778, 6787.66666666667, 4943.91666666667, 3934.08333333333, 
4480.84210526316, 1938.10526315789, 2255.8, 647, 2805, 525.75, 
11059.3571428571, 12257.3571428571, 10462.8823529412, 6944.58823529412, 
1426.16666666667, 531.166666666667, 1398.5625, 234.8125, 7600.85714285714, 
6012.57142857143, 8072.29411764706, 3578.58823529412, 5668.84615384615, 
3860.07692307692, 5760.11764705882, 2230.47058823529)), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Prior to plotting make `month` a factor like `df$month <- factor(df$month, month.name)`. If you want to exclude months from your plot then subset the data before plotting.

Comment: Doing that removed all the `month` names from the data frame, except for September

Comment: The data you have posted to your question only has `month` equal to `September`.

Comment: Right, but I just used a snippet of the data frame, since the whole thing is 48 lines. Every 4 lines it switches to a new month

Comment: Please post your data by pasting the output of `dput(df)` to your question. Otherwise, I don't know what your data looks like.

Comment: Oh shoot I didn't know you could do that! Thanks, posting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim the excess whitespace using the `trimws` base function.

```
# turn month into a factor
df$month <- factor(trimws(df$month, "both"), month.name)

df <- subset(df, !month %in% month.name[1:4])


ggplot(df, aes(x = month, 
               y = mean_ride_count,
               group = mean_ride_type)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Your problem comes from the extra whitespace in your `month` column:

```
head(df$month)
[1] "September" "September" "September" "September" "May      " "May      "
```

Which will not match the built-in `month.name` vector:

```
month.name
[1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"     
 [8] "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December"
```

Comment: The extra whitespace indeed was the issue. I used str_trim() to fix that column and voila, the plot shows 4 beautiful lines like it should. Thank you so much!